# Floating or inline-block pictures next to each other with equal distances to the container's borders

Tags: html, css

I'm  creating a website with a "impressions"-page. This page was planned to look something like this:

[mock-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTCqc.png)

I tried to achieve this by setting the images to inline-block/Float and setting the margin to auto. However, this didn't really work. I can't use a fixed margin, as all of this of course has to be responsible. The div is scaling as it's width is simply defined by width, the pictures are supposed to have a certain minimum size and scale up when the page scales up. (achieved by setting their width to f.e. 50px+0.5vw) Also with decreasing page size, the amount of images in a row should be decreased, in this case, setting a minimum size does the trick for me.

Code example:

```
<body>
    <div id = "FloatingImageContainer">
        <img src = "images\miniImages\1.jpg" class = "FloatingImage"></img>
        <img src = "images\miniImages\2.jpg" class = "FloatingImage"></img>
        <img src = "images\miniImages\3.jpg" class = "FloatingImage"></img>
        <img src = "images\miniImages\4.jpg" class = "FloatingImage"></img>
        <img src = "images\miniImages\5.jpg" class = "FloatingImage"></img>
        <img src = "images\miniImages\6.jpg" class = "FloatingImage"></img>
    </div>
</body>

.FloatingImage {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(50px + 3vw);
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
}

#FloatingImageContainer {
    background-color: red;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Anybody out there who knows how to do this without a framework? I promise, next time I'll use Bootstrap but this is the last page for this website and I'd really like to get over with it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: Added some examples - however, there's no such thing as a current state on this. It's pretty much all a mess right now.

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/wmgzQy

Comment: css id names should be same as you used in your HTML

Comment: #FloatingImageContainer and .FloatingImage

Comment: Yeah, at some point they were, that's not it, as I said. No current state, just things I tried to mess with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is the centering of the images, which get in the next line, display:flex could be the solution:

```css
.FloatingImage {
  /*display: inline-block;
    width: calc(50px + 3vw);
    height: auto;*/
  margin: 10px;
  /*or whatever you want*/
}

#FloatingImageContainer {
  background-color: red;
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="FloatingImageContainer">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/50/?random" class="FloatingImage"></img>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/50/?random" class="FloatingImage"></img>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/50/?random" class="FloatingImage"></img>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/50/?random" class="FloatingImage"></img>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/50/?random" class="FloatingImage"></img>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/50/?random" class="FloatingImage"></img>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This looks great ... However, what does display: flex do exactly and could you please elaborate on  why my code didn't work?

Comment: Your code would have been problematic if there were for example on 5 images, then there would be only 2 in the second row and these would not be centered anymore

And this is a nice page to see what flex can do: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Another thing came up ... When i use this method and set the images' width to f.e. 50px the height remains 100%. Setting height to auto won't change that.... Any idea what this could be about?

Comment: You can wrap the image in a div and style the div with flex and the image width height and width or you could try to find the right flex-style for the image so it is scaled normally.

Comment: I just created a new question haha... Still, thank you, I'll try!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, update your CSS id and class name to match with HTML and use flexbox to achieve expected result

```
  #FloatingImageContainer {
     background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#FloatingImageContainer > img{
  flex: 1 0 0;
  /*demo*/
  border: red solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;

}

.FloatingImage{
    width: 100%;
}
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/wmgzQy

Comment: Hi! Thanks but no, sorry that won't work. I know the HTML and CSS ids and classes don't match anymore but that's just because those where just examples from different versions. I tried it with matching ids and classes but it didn't work. Just wanted to give some code examples.